# Multiple random variable, their expected values, markov chains

Tags: probability

I'm reading a paper "Modeling TCP Throughput: A Simple Model and its Empirical Validation"

In this paper, they modeled TCP throughput using a Markov regenerative process.

Question 1.
There are three probability variables $Y_i$, $\alpha_i$, $W_i$.
Given "$Y_i = \alpha_i + W_i - 1$", they directly used that "$E[Y] = E[\alpha] + E[W] - 1$".
Is it correct? Why is this correct?

Question 2.
There is "$W_i = W_{i-1} / 2 + X_i / b$", where $W_i$ is the Markov chain.
Given that, they used that "$E[W] = E[W] / 2 + E[X] / b$" with assumption 
that $W_i$ and $X_i$ are independent. I don't know why this is valid.

Please help me, thank for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and none requires independence. This stems from the fact that for **every** (integrable) random variables $U$ and $V$, $E[U+V]=E[U]+E[V]$.

To see why this holds, remember that expectations are nothing but integrals and that, for every (integrable with respect to $\mu$) functions $f$ and $g$,
$$
\int(f+g)\mathrm d\mu=\int f\mathrm d\mu+\int g\mathrm d\mu.
$$
Independence is useful to compute the expectations of products, not sums. If $U$ and $V$ are independent (and integrable) random variables then one knows that ($UV$ is integrable and that) $E[UV]=E[U]\cdot E[V]$.

To sum up, in the context of this question, independence and the Markov property are irrelevant.